# List of formats (eg. %@, %f, %i) in NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

When you put variables in strings, somewhat of a concatenation, you do @"%@", blah in objective-c.  I know that there is @"%@", @"%f", @"%i", etc.  Can you please list them out along with their different formats?  That would be very helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: If you look at the stringWithFormat: method in the NSString class reference, it gives you a link to the documentation that describes the format specifiers.

Comment: I would suggest asking what they are called, rather than asking us to produce a list. That could lead to some research of a list that already exists. They are format specifiers. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Perhaps you should consult the documentation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's far too many 'format specifiers' to list.  I can't say it any better than the documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html